Misdemeanor crime. Bein charged w/ hx and have documentaton of another person taking ownership
Would someone still be charged with a misdemeanor crime if another person wrote a letter stating that he take ownership of said crime?

What do you mean by take ownership? They're admitting that they committed the crime?

If the evidence points to the first person, and the police don't believe the second person's confession, I don't see why the police would change who they charge.


Would someone still be charged with a misdemeanor crime if another
person wrote a letter stating that he take ownership of said crime?

Law enforcement officers and prosecutors are not required to believe a letter from another person claiming that they, and not their current suspect, committed the crime.
The letter from someone else claiming that they committed the crime is exculpatory evidence that would be admissible at trial in the defendant's case (if it can be authenticated). And, this would influence whether the prosecutors would decide to bring a case. But it isn't a bar to bringing charges.
It is not at all uncommon for judges to refuse to set aside convictions based upon a confession from a third-party that they actually committed the crime.

as you know, innocence is not necessarily a good appeal
